# XSockets do not connect from Firefox

Tags: angularjs, firefox, xsockets.net

I need to use web sockets for some interactions with the user. I have pretty much copypasted solution from here - http://xsockets.net/blog/angular-js-xsocketsnet and got an issue with Firefox (27.0.1).

When I try to make this call (TwoWayBinding is my XSockets controller, I'm using .NET MVC on host side):

```
var connect = function (url) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    socket = new XSockets.WebSocket(url);
    socket.on(XSockets.Events.open, function (conn) {
        $rootScope.$apply(function () {
            deferred.resolve(conn);
        });
    });
    return deferred.promise;
};

connect("ws://localhost:49200/TwoWayBinding").then(function (ctx) {
    isConnected = true;
    queued.forEach(function (msg, i) {
        publish(msg.t, msg.d);
    });
queued = [];
});
```

I always get an error from Firebug:

Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at ws://localhost:49200/TwoWayBinding.
this.webSocket = new window.WebSocket(url, subprotocol || "XSocketsNET");

The same code works well in Chrome, it gets connected and I'm getting messages sent from host. Mentioned methods are wrapped into angular service, but this all works, I do not think this should be a problem.

One thing I was able to figure out from Fiddler was this:

**Chrome:**

Result  Protocol    Host    URL Body    Caching Content-Type    Process Comments    Custom
3   200 HTTP    Tunnel to   localhost:49200 0           chrome:3976

Result  Protocol    Host    URL Body    Caching Content-Type    Process Comments    Custom
6   101 HTTP    localhost:49200 /TwoWayBinding?XSocketsClientStorageGuid=5cf5c99aafd141d1b247ed70107659e0   0           chrome:3976

**Firefox:**

Result  Protocol Host URL Body Caching  Content-Type    Process Comments    Custom
1740    200 HTTP    Tunnel to   localhost:49200 0           firefox:1420

Result  Protocol    Host    URL Body    Caching Content-Type    Process Comments    Custom
1741     -  HTTP    localhost:49200 /TwoWayBinding  -1          firefox:1420

Simply said - there is some additional parameter XSocketsClientStorageGuid in the response for Chrome which does not occur in the respose to FF. I'm not sure if that has any impact or if I'm completely wrong but will appreciate any advice if somebody experiences same issue.

**Update:**
It looks like the critical line is this one

```
socket = new XSockets.WebSocket(url);
```

as the socket is not created properly in Firefox. But I still not have the cause of this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What version are you running on , did you make a new installation of XSockets.NET using the Nuget Package or did you use the git example mentioned in the quesion above?

I just did a test on FF 26.0 and 27.0.1 , and it did go well using this pice of example;

http://xsockets.github.io/XSockets.JavaScript.API/test/index.html

I will have a look at the old Angular example asap and makre sure it is fixed of there is a problem!

Kind regards

Magnus

Comment: I have installed XSockets using Nuget and then Package Manager Console too. With the same results.

From my observation I never get called this method which should be bind to  XSockets.Events.open event.

    this.bind(XSockets.Events.open, function (data) { ...

and later gets called this with the error mentioned above

   this.webSocket.onerror = function (err) {
       if (self.onerror) self.onerror(er);
           self.dispatchEvent(XSockets.Events.onError, err);
   };

Comment: I have installed XSockets version 3.0.4.1. Running on .NET framework 4.5 using MVC 4.

Comment: Hi,  There is a know issue in 3.0.4.1  , We fixed that and the new patch will be released today (3/2 2014) , stay tunded om XSockets.NET or our Twitter feed @Xsockets , and you will get notified when u can downkoad.  Thank you very much for providing us with valuble info!